# What is the difference between port and localport?

Tags: java, network-programming, port

When i print the object of a `Socket` class  in java, it prints the socket details like this--
`Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=49989,localport=10]`.I know about port number.But i don't understand why two port numbers(port and localport) are there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per the javadocs

> localPort - the local port the socket is bound to, or zero for a
>   system selected free port.

For the other process the port number will be 49989, but this process will be using port 10.

Imagine a telephone call, the number you ring is 49989, but your telephone number is 10

Comment: When i specified the port number(10) while making object of Client socket.Then why this local port ?